# how to add an SCTP port using firewall-cmd in CentOS

Tags: linux, firewall, centos7, sctp

I want to open an SCTP port on a firewall using firewall-cmd command on CentOS7.1 server
I have tried to add by using

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=portnumber/sctp
```

I am getting an error response..

```
Error: INVALID_PROTOCOL: sctp
```

I have tried to add the protocol to the /etc/modprobe.d directory path..

```
echo "install sctp /bin/false" > /etc/modprobe.d/sctp.conf
```

Without Success(it did not bring any difference)..

If I do  `lsmod | grep sctp`, I get the below response (which means sctp protocol has been allowed)

```
xt_sctp                12853  0  
sctp                  217455  6  
libcrc32c              12644  1 sctp  
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

if I stop the firewall, I can see the connections established with

```
netstat -lanp|grep sctp
```

But if I start the firewall I see the below errors on the server log

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpChannelImpl.finishConnect(SctpChannelImpl.java:475)
```

Plus,there are no established sctp connections from the netstat output.

Comment: Is the sctp module loaded (`sudo modprobe sctp`). What does `checksctp` say?

Comment: checksctp gives the proper response          
SCTP supported


 sudo modprobe sctp  
goes successfully without any output response ..

Answer (score 1):

If it still relevant, firewalld start support sctp and dccp in ports, source-ports, forward-ports for CentOS from version of RPM [0.4.4.4](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.4.1708/x86_64/Packages/firewall-config-0.4.4.4-6.el7.noarch.html)

The easiest way to check if your firewalld support sctp is to run command:

```
firewall-cmd -V
```

to check firewalld version
or just search for sctp in (to start search inside man: /sctp)

```
man firewall-cmd
```

if sctp not supported you will not find sctp string inside man pages